# Generate records in an R data frame between two dates

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame that consists of customers scheduled subscription payments as follows:

```r
CusID <- c(1,2,3)
FromDate <- c(ymd("2019-01-01"), ymd("2019-01-04"), ymd("2019-02-02"))
ToDate <-c(ymd("2019-01-16"), ymd("2019-01-15"), ymd("2019-04-03"))
Amount <- c(5,10,12)
Frequency <- c("Weekly", "Fortnightly", "Monthly")
Input <-  data.frame(CusID, Amount, Frequency, FromDate, ToDate)
```

For each row (customer), I wish to loop from the FromDate to the ToDate and output one row of each data for each scheduled payment that falls between those dates, resulting in the following data frame:

```r
CusID <- c(1,1,1,2,3,3,3)
PaymentDate <- c(ymd("2019-01-01"), ymd("2019-01-08"), ymd("2019-01-15"),
                 ymd("2019-01-04"),ymd("2019-02-02"),ymd("2019-03-02"),ymd("2019-04-02"))
Amount <- c(5,5,5,10,12,12,12)
Output <-  data.frame(CusID, PaymentDate, Amount)
```

What is an efficient way to achieve this using R (and preferably using dplyr / tidyverse functions)?

In SAS my approach would be to use a DO / WHILE LOOP and OUTPUT statement to write a new line for each scheduled payment. e.g.

```
data Output;
set Input;
PaymentDate = FromDate;
do while (PaymentDate < ToDate);
Payment = Amount;
PaymentDate = PaymentDate + (7 / 14 / 30 ~ logic based on Frequency);
output;
loop;
run;
```

(The key here in SAS is the output statement - it explicitly writes a new record each time it is invoked, thus can be used in a loop to write multiple output lines per input line).

Is there an equivalent method available in R, or is a different approach recommended?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option using `tidyverse`

```
Input %>%
  mutate(Frequency = case_when(Frequency == "Weekly" ~ 7L,
                               Frequency == "Fortnightly" ~ 14L,
                               Frequency == "Monthly" ~ 30L,
                               TRUE ~ 0L)) %>%
  group_by(CusID) %>%
  group_modify(~ {PaymentDate <- seq.Date(from = .x$FromDate, to = .x$ToDate, by = .x$Frequency) 
                 crossing(.x[,1], PaymentDate)})  


# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   CusID [3]
  CusID PaymentDate Amount
  <dbl> <date>       <dbl>
1     1 2019-01-01       5
2     1 2019-01-08       5
3     1 2019-01-15       5
4     2 2019-01-04      10
5     3 2019-02-02      12
6     3 2019-03-04      12
7     3 2019-04-03      12
```

Payment dates are a little different from your expected output because `seq.Date` adds 30 days taking into account the different number of days in those months.

**UPDATE:**

Here is a more verbatim solution

```
Input %>% 
  mutate(PaymentDate = FromDate,
         RFrequency = case_when(Frequency == "Weekly" ~ '1 week',
                                Frequency == "Fortnightly" ~ '2 weeks',
                                Frequency == "Monthly" ~ '1 month')) %>% 
  group_by(CusID, Amount) %>% 
  expand(PaymentDate = seq.Date(FromDate,ToDate, by = RFrequency)) 

# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   CusID, Amount [3]
  CusID Amount PaymentDate
  <dbl>  <dbl> <date>     
1     1      5 2019-01-01 
2     1      5 2019-01-08 
3     1      5 2019-01-15 
4     2     10 2019-01-04 
5     3     12 2019-02-02 
6     3     12 2019-03-02 
7     3     12 2019-04-02
```

Comment: This is way better!

Comment: I'm going to try this out now.  As you point out, the potential limitation with this method regards the simplification of the month / 30 day thing.  My bad - I should have been a bit more specific about that as I can see it will be an issue.  In SAS I would use an INTNX date offset function, that allows you to shift by a "whole" month - I guess an equivalent in R would be using something from lubridate.  It looks like the answer below (user2474226) blends some of this answer with a way of handling that.  I'll report back with my findings.

Comment: If that is what you want you can just change the `case_when()` part. Instead of numbers assign `"1 week"`, `"2 weeks"`, `"1 month"` and `""`instead of `0L`. It will work.

Comment: Expand tidyr function - perfect!

Answer (score 1):

I tweaked your Input data.frame so that the Frequency values are strings, not factors.

You could create a helper table freq_mapping to convert from your Frequency to the frequency format R likes. This would avoid the 30 day issue that one of the other answers pointed out.

```
freq_mapping <- data.frame(Frequency=c('Weekly', 'Fortnightly', 'Monthly'), 
                           RFrequency = c('1 week', '2 weeks', '1 month'),
                           stringsAsFactors =  FALSE)
```

Then merge Input with this:

```
Input <- Input %>%
    inner_join(freq_mapping, by = 'Frequency')
```

Now you can create the payment dates:

```
Input$PaymentDate <- Input$FromDate
Input %>% 
    group_by(CusID) %>% 
    complete(PaymentDate = seq.Date(FromDate,ToDate, by = RFrequency)) %>% 
    fill(PaymentDate,Amount) %>% 
    select(CusID, PaymentDate, Amount)
```

Comment: Yes!  That does it.  I've updated your solution to include the frequency mapping into the dplyr step.

Answer (score 0):

not so easy problem for me. The solution is not beautiful but it should somehow do the work. You'll see there is a problem for the monthly payment which is not always 30, but otherwise it should work. But nicer solution surely exist.

```
    library(data.table)
Input <-  data.frame(CusID, Amount, Frequency, FromDate, ToDate)

Input=data.table(Input)
Input[Frequency=="Weekly",freq:=7][Frequency=="Fortnightly",freq:=14][Frequency=="Monthly",freq:=30]
Input[,Ratio:=(ToDate-FromDate)/freq]

#What is the maximum rows ? for a customer ?
NREP=as.integer(max(ceiling(Input$Ratio)))

Input[,Rep:=1][,PaymentDate:=FromDate]
for(i in 1:NREP){
Inputtemp=copy(Input)
Inputtemp[,FromDate:=FromDate+freq]
Input=rbind(Input,Inputtemp)  
}

#Remove invalid rows
Input=unique(Input)

Input=Input[!(FromDate>ToDate),]
setorder(Input,CusID)
Input=Input[,c("CusID","FromDate","Amount")]
setnames(Input,"FromDate","PaymentDate")
Input==data.table(Output)
```

Answer (score 0):

A mashup of Humpelstielzchen and user2474226's answers, to bring all logic into a single dplyr step.

```r
Output <- Input %>% 
  mutate(PaymentDate = FromDate,
         RFrequency = case_when(Frequency == "Weekly" ~ '1 week',
                                Frequency == "Fortnightly" ~ '2 weeks',
                                Frequency == "Monthly" ~ '1 month')) %>% 
  group_by(CusID) %>% 
  complete(PaymentDate = seq.Date(FromDate,ToDate, by = RFrequency)) %>% 
  fill(PaymentDate,Amount) %>% 
  select(CusID, PaymentDate, Amount)
```

Comment: Interesting mashup. Just curious: What makes this solution ideal to you?

Comment: I like the separation of complete and fill on to two lines - you can see what each step is doing by breaking into and running in two parts.

I wasn't familiar with the crossing approach that you proposed and even though both are part of tidyr, I just preferred the complete / fill method.

As with many things in R, it seems there are many ways to skin a cat :-)

Comment: I get that. If you prefer a more verbatim solution check out my update.